# quickCheck errors out with segmentation fault: 11

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am working through "Haskell - the craft of functional programming", and have hit a really weird issue:

I have the following two functions defined:

```
averageThree :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Float
averageThree a b c = (fromIntegral (a + b + c)) / 3

howManyAboveAverage :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer

howManyAboveAverage a b c
    | (a == b) && (b == c) && (a == c) = 0
    | (fromIntegral a > (averageThree a b c) && (fromIntegral b > (averageThree a b c) || fromIntegral c > (averageThree a b c))) || (fromIntegral b > (averageThree a b c) && fromIntegral c > (averageThree a b c))  = 2
    | otherwise = 1
```

Which seem to both produce the desired results. I then have the following quickCheck properties defined:

```
prop_averageThree1, prop_averageThree2, prop_averageThree3, prop_howManyAboveAverage :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool

prop_averageThree1 a b c = (((averageThree a b c) * (fromIntegral 3)) == (fromIntegral (a + b + c)))
prop_averageThree2 a b c = (fromIntegral a >= averageThree a b c) || (fromIntegral b >= averageThree a b c) || (fromIntegral c >= averageThree a b c)
prop_averageThree3 a b c = (fromIntegral a <= averageThree a b c) || (fromIntegral b <= averageThree a b c) || (fromIntegral c <= averageThree a b c)
prop_howManyAboveAverage a b c = (0 <= howManyAboveAverage a b c) && (2 >= howManyAboveAverage a b c)
```

All of these properties when run with `quickCheck prop_name` produce:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

My module definition is as follows:

```
module Chapter3 where
import Data.Char
import Test.QuickCheck
```

What is causing this error message?

Comment: segfaults indicate a serious underlying problem. could be memory issues or ghc runtime bugs. what version of ghc are you using? or are you using hugs?

Comment: Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.4.2, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.0.3

Comment: Operating system? Available memory?

Comment: You might try building with `--disable-optimization`. Whenever QuickCheck has died on me, disabling optimisation solved the problem. That is, it allowed QuickCheck to complete, and tell me what tests failed.

Comment: How are you running the tests (from GHCi or from main)? What QuickCheck version are you using (use `ghc-pkg list QuickCheck` to find out)?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.4.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2/package.conf.d
   QuickCheck-2.5.1.1
/Users/abe/.ghc/i386-darwin-7.4.2/package.conf.d

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5 and have 8GB of RAM.
How do I pass --disable-optimization into ghci?

Comment: I tried your code just now, in GHCi, and all of the tests passed. So you can forget my `--disable-optimization` suggestion (which is a flag you pass to `cabal`).

Comment: At the command line, type `ghc-pkg check`. Are any problems reported? Apart from this problem, has your Haskell installation worked OK, or have you had other symptoms?

Comment: Abes-MacBook-Pro:~ abe$ ghc-pkg check
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Users/abe/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/Craft3e-0.1.0.9/doc/html/Craft3e.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0/doc/html/haskell-platform.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0/doc/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/GLUT-2.1.2.1/doc/html/GLUT.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file

Comment: And no, I haven't had any other issues (that I am aware of)

Comment: Is there like a verbose mode that will let me see more errors then just "seg fault 11"?